# How do you show/hide a div with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

I'm trying to use javascript to show/hide a div's content depending on which radio button is selected. I have an onchange function that I use to change the the div content from one div to another, but it doesn't work. If you can do this in jquery instead thats ok but im not that familiar with jquery so if you could update my jsfiddle with it I would be appreciativw :) Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/markusbond/au77Ladg/
Any help is appreciated :)

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    function changeSelection() {

        if (document.getElementById("selectionTables").checked) {
            document.getElementById("populateCheckBoxes").show;
            document.getElementById("unpopulateCheckBoxes").hidden;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("unpopulateCheckBoxes").show;
            document.getElementById("populateCheckBoxes").hidden;
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<form role="form">
  <div class="row">
    <!--this is the onchange call-->
    <div class="radio col-xs-2" id="populateSelection" onchange="changeSelection()">
      <!--this is the first radio button-->
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="selectionTables" />Use Tables
      </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <!--this is the second radio button-->
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="selectionViews" />Use Views
      </label>
    </div>
    <!--this is the first changed div-->
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="populateCheckBoxes">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="selectionCondition" />Condition
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="selectionDistribution" />Distribution
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="selectionProgram" />Program
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="selectionTreatment" />Treatment
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--this is the second changed div-->
  <div class="row" id="unpopulateCheckBoxes"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you certain this isn't a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31036088/javascript-onchange-function-doesnt-work

Comment: Why did you reinvent yourself from Mark B to Markus Mr. Bond?!

Comment: The div doesn't fire `onchange()` event. Put that attribute on the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way

```
  <script>
   function changeSelection() {

       if (document.getElementById("selectionTables").checked) {
          document.getElementById("populateCheckBoxes").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("unpopulateCheckBoxes").style.visibility = "visible";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("unpopulateCheckBoxes").style.visibility ="hidden";
        document.getElementById("populateCheckBoxes").style.visibility = "visible";
      }
  }
 </script>
```

You are using

```
document.getElementById("unpopulateCheckBoxes").hidden;
```

but you should

```
document.getElementById("populateCheckBoxes").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Hope this helps

Comment: lol sorry totally was commenting on the wrong answer :p but i couldnt get it to work, mind updating fiddle?

Comment: This does not show and hide the divs, but rather changes their visibility. The div is still theoretically "visible," but cannot be seen. This is a nuance created by CSS wordiage between display and visibility properties.

Answer (score 2):

Example using JQuery [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/au77Ladg/1/)

JavaScript

```
$('input:radio[name=optradio]').change(
function(){
       if (this.value == 'selectionTables') {
        $("#unpopulateCheckBoxes" ).hide();
        $("#populateCheckBoxes").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#unpopulateCheckBoxes" ).show();
        $("#populateCheckBoxes").hide();
    }
}
);
```

Give your first radio button a value `value="selectionTables"`

```
<!--this is the first radio button-->
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="selectionTables" value="selectionTables" />Use Tables
</label>
```

I hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: You totally understood my question, Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('myElementID').style.display = 'none'; // Will hide an element
document.getElementById('myElementID').style.display = 'block'; // Will show an element
```

It is worth noting that you will not always want your element to be `display:block;`. There are many display options and you probably want to toggle back and forth based on how your element was originally shown.

Comment: I feel like this should work but when i tried implementing it into my jsfiddle it didnt work. Do you mind updating my jsfiddle so i can see it working please?

Comment: It's possible that the "onchange" event is not firing and that is not what this question is about.

Comment: If you're not going to accept my answer even though you asked how to show and hide divs using Javascript and NOT toggle visibility, you could at least upvote for the time I spent on the fiddle.

Comment: I dont have enough rep to do so

Comment: No worries, you'll get there. Good luck on your JS endeavors.

Answer (score 1):

or via jquery, thats what i would prefer:

```
function changeSelection() {

    if ($("#selectionTables").attr("checked") {
        $("#populateCheckBoxes").show();
        $("#unpopulateCheckBoxes").hide();
    } else {
        $("#unpopulateCheckBoxes").show();
        $("#populateCheckBoxes").hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Im not familiar with jquery and as such i can never get it to work, not sure if i need to add a reference to get it working. So do you mind updating my jsfiddle since im a jquery noob please :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is html does not supports `show/hide` attribute. Try using `style` attribute with `display` property. Also use `checked` attribute to make default radio selection.

```
<input type="radio" name="optradio" id="selectionTables" checked='' />
```

```js
function changeSelection() {
  var pop = "none",
    upop = "block";
  if (document.getElementById("selectionTables").checked) {
    pop = "block";
    upop = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById("unpopulateCheckBoxes").style.display = upop;
  document.getElementById("populateCheckBoxes").style.display = pop;
}
```

```html
<form role="form">
  <div class="row">
    <!--this is the onchange call-->
    <div class="radio col-xs-2" id="populateSelection" onchange="changeSelection()">
      <!--this is the first radio button-->
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="selectionTables" checked='' />Use Tables
      </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <!--this is the second radio button-->
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="selectionViews" />Use Views
      </label>
    </div>
    <!--this is the first changed div-->
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="populateCheckBoxes">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="selectionCondition" />Condition
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="selectionDistribution" />Distribution
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="selectionProgram" />Program
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="selectionTreatment" />Treatment
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--this is the second changed div-->
  <div class="row" id="unpopulateCheckBoxes"></div>
</form>
```